# PartialFunction that needs access to an outer val

Tags: scala

I have code like this:

```
def begin() = {
  val processor = ???
  db.insert(v).map {
     case Left(....) =>
     case Right(...) => proccessor.do(...)
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a partial function version so I can do this:

```
   def begin(pf: PartialFunction[Either[CustomError, String], Boolean) = {
      val processor = ???
      db.insert(v).map {
         pf
      }
    }
```

The problem is, the partial function `pf` needs access to `processor` to perform something important for this transaction.

Is it possible for the partial function to somehow gain access to this `processor` val?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the most basic way of dependency injection, parameters.

So instead of just receiving a `PartialFunction`, you can ask for a `Function` that takes a `Processor` and return the `PartialFunction` you want to use.

```scala
def begin(pf: Processor => PartialFunction[Either[CustomError, String], Boolean]) = {
  val processor = ???
  db.insert(v).map {
    pf(processor)
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
begin { processor =>
  case Left(...) =>
  case Right(...) => proccessor.do(...)
}
```

---

Another option would be to accept two handlers, one for the **Right** and one for the **Left** like this:

```scala
def begin(successHandler: (Processor, String) => Boolean)(errorHandler: CustomError => Boolean) = {
  val processor = ???
  db.insert(v).map {
    case Right(str) => successHandler(processor, str)
    case Left(error) => errorHanlder(error)
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
begin {
  case (processor, str) =>
    proccessor.do(...)
} { error =>
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to design this in a way where the user passing in the partial function can use any dependancy they want?  Like maybe the want to log to the database if its an error, and for success to something custom using any library they want?  Or this isn't possible...

Comment: @Blankman and how would you magically instantiate and pass anything the user wants1?